# Cannot perform binary operators on dbl's even though they're numeric?

Tags: r

This is my tibble.

[Preview of tibble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD5Ik.png)

Simply trying to find the % of count (cases) in population. Shouldn't the '/' work on dbls?

[Error I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doF43.png)

Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question to make it easier for others to modify your code and spot errors. Your question would also benefit from being more specific.

Putting together the pieces from your screenshots, I assume you would like to create a new column by dividing an existing column by another existing column. The function to do this is `mutate()`, not `add_column()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  country = "Australia", 
  count = 8,
  population = 18.4
)

df |> mutate(pct_pop = (count / 1e6) / population)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 4
#>   country   count population     pct_pop
#>   <chr>     <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 Australia     8       18.4 0.000000435
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

It looks a bit odd that you are dividing the cases by a million, rather than population. Make sure you didn't get that wrong.